# Laravel 4 Environments not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if someone could help out.

I have run through the environment setup for Laravel 4 and it doesnt seem to be working.

In my MAMP setup, i created protected.dev host

In my Bootstrap->start.php i have my local url like so

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('protected.dev')
));
```

I have created a 'local' directory in the app->config directory, copied over the standard database.php file and then modified the database.php file inside the 'local' directory.

When i try and show the site, i get the

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

which is in the standard config->database.php file.

It doesnt seem to be detecting its a local environment for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In laravel 4, the enviroments are set by the machine name, not by the web server url.

To determine your hostname use the hostname terminal command.

Type hostname in your terminal (this works on linux and mac) and cut and paste the result in your start.php file in the local variable and it should work fine.

example:

> angoru@angel-mountain:~$ hostname
>
> angel-mountain

my start.php

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('angel-mountain'), // Change this to your local machine hostname.
  'staging' => array('your-staging-machine-name'),
  'production' => array('your-production-machine-name'),
));
```

For more explanation: [Environment Configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: That solves that problem ... Thanks alot for that! ... Do i need to set my app.php 'url' to anything?

Comment: It's not necesary for the site to work but you should need it when running Artisan tasks.

Comment: That makes sense ... So if its using the environment to auto detect local or production, what should the url be set to?

Comment: `php artisan env` will display the current application environment

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 4 doesn't rely on virtual host to detect the working environment any more. It now uses the machine's hostname to do it. So you need to change `protected.dev` to your machine's hostname. On Linux, you can find out your machine's hostname by running the following command in the terminal:

```
hostname
```

More on this http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration

Answer (score 1):

In environments with several developers each one may add its hostname to the 'local' array in start.php:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('user1-hostname','user2-hostname'), // Developers local hostnames
  'staging' => array('your-staging-machine-name'),
  'production' => array('your-production-machine-name'),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you test Laravel project using localhost domain or some other virtual hosts without dots (what I usually do), it might be helpful to use such code in `bootstrap/start.php`:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'.') === false) {  
      return 'local';  
  }
  return 'production';
});
```

after:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
```

This makes that even you move your code into other directory or move to another machine/another virtual host without dots, you don't have to add machine name into `local` machines.

You can of course add more rules to that (include `127.0.0.1` or some hosts with `.dev` name) if you need.